# How to get code from a GitHub repo onto another domain?

Tags: html, hosting

I'm developing a site and before I start paying to host it, I've been using a cheap hosting software called AWARDSPACE.com with a random free URL. The software has a difficult interface and whenever you want to change the site you have to go through a whole process. I was wondering if there is some kind of widget of some sort to take code from GitHub (where I'm storing all the code, for safekeeping) to this site in just a few lines rather than constantly updating the site from my dashboard. And before you suggest it, GitHub pages doesn't work for me for [unknown problems.](https://superuser.com/questions/1397260/github-desktop-repository-changing-repo-names) One other solution I can think of is a different hosting service if anyone has any suggestions

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What are you using at the moment?

Comment: Its called AWARDSPACE.com  Ill add that to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that the best solution for you is Heroku, which has a free plan and can be linked up with your repository in order to automatically redeploy your site after every push.

But be aware that in order the serve a simple HTML site you need an `index.php` file with the following content `<?php header( 'Location: /index.html' ) ;  ?>`

I have just deployed this HTML site directly from my GitHub repository: [Heroku HTML site](https://staticsitestack.herokuapp.com)

This is from their DevCenter

> Accounts are given a base of 550 free dyno hours each month. In addition to these base hours, accounts which verify with a credit card will receive an additional 450 hours added to the monthly free dyno quota. This means you can receive a total of 1000 free dyno hours per month, if you verify your account with a credit card.
>
> When you use all your free dyno hours for a given month, all free apps on your account will be forced to sleep for the rest of the month.
>
> Every Heroku account is allocated a pool of free dyno hours. An app actively consumes free dyno hours if the app is set to use free dynos and any of the following are true:
>
> It has a web dyno that is receiving traffic (i.e., not sleeping)
>
> It has a worker dyno running
>
> It has a one-off dyno running. For example, one started via the CLI or Scheduler.
> If an app has a free web dyno, and that dyno receives no web traffic in a 30-minute period, it will sleep.
>
> Free web dynos do not consume free dyno hours while sleeping.
>
> If a sleeping web dyno receives web traffic, it will become active again after a short delay (assuming your account has free dyno hours available).

So, in conclusion: Unless you have continuous web traffic to your site for more than 550(or 1000) hours you will have no real problem.

You can read more about dynos over [here](https://www.heroku.com/dynos)

Comment: My only question is, is it totally free? This is only my beta development site